# How to call a function from inside a class?

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I am new to Python but I have figured out a few cool things already. I have recently written a couple of classes to draw buttons / text boxes for an application to print labels at work.
I need to cycle through some records on my sql server - the connectivity works OK so I won't post all of that code.

I have a function `getNextPart()`that calls the next item from a table on my sql server- the intention is when I click my "+" spinner button, it runs `getnextpart()` and assigns that to a global parameter. The same would happen for `getprevpart()` when I click the "-" button.

When I click the "+" button the handler event does everything as expected, but doesn't run the `getnextpart()` function at all. It doesn't run the print statement or anything, so I am suspecting that it isn't the database connector that is broken. There are also no errors being reported. I tried including `getnextpart` as a method and referring to it as `self.getnextpart()` but that didn't work for me either.  I have searched for a couple of days but can't find anything, so I'm asking for some guidance here please.

How (or even can I) call a function from within the `handle_event()` method of the `SpinnerButton` class?

This is my program, excluding the mysql connector and other parameters initialised at the start.

```
# Initialise global variables for display on the screen
partnumber = ''

def getnextpart():

    global partnumber

    print(str('Get Next Part should run here !!'))
    dbcurs=cnx.cursor()
    cnx.commit()
    query = 'spGetNextItem'
    args=[partnumber]
    result_args = dbcurs.callproc(query ,args)

    for result in dbcurs.stored_results():
        itemresult = result.fetchone()
        itemcode = str(itemresult[0])

    partnumber = itemcode
    print(partnumber)

def getprevpart():

    global partnumber

    dbcurs=cnx.cursor()
    cnx.commit()
    query = 'spGetPrevItem'
    args=[partnumber]
    result_args = dbcurs.callproc(query ,args)

    for result in dbcurs.stored_results():
        itemresult = result.fetchone()
        itemcode = str(itemresult[0])

    partnumber = itemcode
    print(partnumber)

class SpinnerButton:

    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h,type,cause):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(x,y,w,h)
        self.color = light_blue
        if type == 'UP':
            self.text = '+'
            self.x_adj = 7
            self.y_adj = 2
        elif type == 'DOWN':
            self.text = '-'
            self.x_adj = 11
            self.y_adj = 5
        else:
            self.txt = '>'
        self.sptorun = cause
        self.dir = type
        self.txt_surface = myfont30.render(self.text, True, black)

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print(str(self.sptorun))
                print(str(self.dir))
                # Toggle the active variable.
                if self.sptorun =='items' and self.dir == 'UP':
                    getnextpart()
                elif self.sptorun == 'items' and self.dir =='DOWN':
                    getprevpart()

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.text)
                    self.text = ''
                elif event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                # Re-render the text.
                self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the rect.
        pg.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 0)
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+self.x_adj, self.rect.y - self.y_adj))




class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text, lbltxt):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = COLOR_INACTIVE
        self.text = text
        self.lbltext = lbltxt
        self.txt_surface = myfont25.render(text, True, blue)
        self.lbltxt_surface = myfont25.render(lbltxt, True, red)
        self.active = False

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False
            # Change the current color of the input box.
            self.color = COLOR_ACTIVE if self.active else COLOR_INACTIVE
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.text)
                    self.text = ''
                elif event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                # Re-render the text.
                self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)

    def update(self):
        # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width = max(200, self.txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        self.rect.w = width

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+2))
        screen.blit(self.lbltxt_surface, (self.rect.x - self.lbltxt_surface.get_width()- 10, self.rect.y))
        # Blit the rect.
        pg.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)






def main():
    global partnumber
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    input_partnumber = InputBox(200, 10, 140, 32, str(partnumber), 'Item: ')
    input_boxes = [input_partnumber]
    spin_itemup = SpinnerButton(400,10,32,33,'UP','item')
    spin_itemdown = SpinnerButton(433,10,32,33,'DOWN','item')
    spin_buttons = [spin_itemup, spin_itemdown]
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)

            for btn in spin_buttons:
                btn.handle_event(event)

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.update()

        # screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        screen.fill(bg)
        for box in input_boxes:
            box.draw(screen)

        for btn in spin_buttons:
            btn.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Calling a function from within a class works exactly as well, and in exactly the same way, as calling a function from anywhere else.  But you are never actually calling the functions; that can only happen if `self.sptorun == 'items'`, but you are creating both spinners with `'item'` instead.

Comment: You should probably tag this question with the GUI library you're using in your program (at least, you should if there's a reasonable chance it's relevant). It looks like `pg` in your code is `pygame`, but we can't actually see the `import` statement to be sure.

Comment: jasonharper - omg I am so stupid. Thank you for pointing out my error in coding there, I really should have seen that. I have tested it now and it works as expected.

Comment: Blckknght - ok, sorry about that - I'll make sure to include those types of things in future. You were right though, I am using pygame. :)